# Angular 2+ keydown combination with "*" asterisk-key for German keyboard

Tags: angular, angular5

I would like to handle keydown event with combination of shift and asterisk-key using German keyboard.

At this moment any other combination i can handle using :

```
 <span class="template-row"
  (click)="passPreviewForDisplay()"
  (keydown.enter)="addTemplateToFroala()"
  (keydown.control.shift.f)="handle($event)"
  (keydown.arrowleft)="closeTree($event)"
  (keydown.arrowright)="openTree($event)">
  {{template.name}}
</span>
```

This is my example cod handling simple cases. I didn't manage to find all available combination for keydown event as well as cannot find information of handling something like keydown.control.shift.*. I emphasize that it should be invoked from German keyboard. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout#/media/File:German-T2-Keyboard-Prototype-May-2012.jpg
The key is next to Ü (on the right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular only provides the shorthand for a subset of keys, you should just listen for any keydown event and use the keyboard event to figure it out in code.

```
<span class="template-row"
  (click)="passPreviewForDisplay()"
  (keydown.enter)="addTemplateToFroala()"
  (keydown.control.shift.f)="handle($event)"
  (keydown.arrowleft)="closeTree($event)"
  (keydown.arrowright)="openTree($event)"
  (keydown)="checkAsterisk($event)">
  {{template.name}}
</span>
```

in controller:

```
const ASTERISK_CODE = 999; //I don't actually know the keycode for the german asterisk but you could find it easily by logging a keydown event from that key
checkAsterisk(kb: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (kb.shiftKey && kb.keyCode === ASTERISK_CODE) {
       console.log('asterisk poressed');
    }
}
```

If this is something you need to do all over your app you could just make a directive for it very easily like:

```
const ASTERISK_CODE = 999; //I don't actually know the keycode for the german asterisk but you could find it easily by logging a keydown event from that key
@Directive({
   selector: '[asteriskPress]',
   host: { '(keydown)': 'checkAsterisk($event)' }
})
export class AsteriskPressDirective {
    @Output() asteriskPress: EventEmitter<KeyboardEvent> = new EventEmitter<KeyboardEvent>();

    checkAsterisk(kb: KeyboardEvent) {
       // check if shift key pressed and keyCode is asterisk
       if (kb.shiftKey && kb.keyCode === ASTERISK_CODE) {
         this.asteriskPress.next(kb);
       }
    }
}
```

then use it in template (after declaring / exporting / importing etc correctly):

```
<span class="template-row"
  (click)="passPreviewForDisplay()"
  (keydown.enter)="addTemplateToFroala()"
  (keydown.control.shift.f)="handle($event)"
  (keydown.arrowleft)="closeTree($event)"
  (keydown.arrowright)="openTree($event)"
  (asteriskPress)="reactToPress($event)">
  {{template.name}}
</span>
```

Comment: Really helpful answer with a step by step instruction. Thank you very much !

Comment: happy to help, I've made custom key directives like this plenty of time, they're very helpful